# expanding divisions in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a HTML page where i have two divisions left and middle inside a wrap division. the middle division contains the content and the left is a navigation menu.
The problem is my middle division gets expanding since it contains the text, i wanted to make the navigation height equal to that of the middle.

the html page is as follows,

```
<div id ="wrap">
<div id="left">
##navigations menu
</div>
<div id="middle">
##content
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS is as follows,

```
#wrap{
color: #000; 
background: #fff; 
margin: 0px auto 0;
width:800px;
}   
#leftnav{
float:left;
width:181px;
min-height:600px;
padding:10px;
margin-left:11px;
background-color:#CCC;
}
#middle {
float:left;
width:538px;
min-height:580px;
padding:20px;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

can anyone help in with this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) will fill your need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical solution to do that. CSS has nothing to adjust the height of an element according to the height of another, *completely independent* element.

You can still use workarounds, but be aware that all those workarounds are **evil**.

- Use table layouts. Yes, that sucks, but it gives you the expected result.
- Adjust the height with JavaScript when the document is ready. Of course you have to take in account that some of your users will not have JavaScript enabled.
- Change your design. For example, if your left side panel has a black background and is 200px width, you can set a black 200px border to your middle division, filling the remaining space, and floatleft your left side panel to hover the border.

You can also try to play with parent `<div/>`s. For example, if you need a border to your left side panel, filling the whole height of the page, you may set a border to the parent `<div/>` and a left border to your middle division element.